# GPS co-ordinates at non-remote areas Android

Tags: android, gps

Hi i know the working principle of GPS. After some R&D on the same, i have some doubts regarding the Global Positioning System

We all know that GPS can work without internet. But will the accuracy be correct in non-remote areas like Desert, mid-sea, dense forest? 
I am in an idea to build an app that utilises, GPS in non-remote areas.

Will the GPS works in restricted areas? For example, in Countries border, ocean border and all?

Comment: GPS collects location from satellite. So it shouldn't matter country border, desert, ocean. What did you mean by restricted areas ? You sure can't locate US Army base or something :D

Comment: The same i am asking mate. Can i locate a army base or Tank manufacturing factory(which might be restricted place) through GPS?

Comment: Nope, I think not. These would be truly restricted.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good article about cell phone GPS accuracy from Community Health Maps. How Accurate is the GPS on my Smartphone? (Part 1 and Part 2)

In this article they explain cell phone A-GPS. The A stands for assisted, in which the phone downloads the GPS ephemeris (data about the GPS satellite constellation). Without data access the GPS may take several minutes to become accurate because the ephemeris would be downloaded from the GPS satellites.

The GPS system does not have border restrictions. It is space based a radio communication. If you have a good view of the sky and have good satellite geometry you can get good positional accuracy. Many new phones now use GNSS instead of GPS. This is US GPS plus Russian GLONASS and other systems. This helps by increasing the number of satellites available, and the GLONASS satellite system is better in high northern latitudes.